# Migrating Windows Server 2012 to NEW 2019 Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, migration, windows-server-2019

I need to migrate a clients Windows 2012 server to a new hardware server with Windows 2019.  The old server is a domain controller and also a file server. I have already stood up the new server with VM 2019 OS. I want to verify I have the right process in place and in correct order...

1. Add new server to domain
2. Add all roles from existing server to new server
3. Promote new server as a DC
4. Install Active Directory services on new server
5. Replicate DNS/DHCP to new server from existing server.
6. Move FSMO roles(schema) to new server
7. Use migration tool or powershell to copy data from old server to new
8. Test login validation on new server capability from domain account
9. Verify data on new server has migrated
10. Demote old server and remove from network

Thanks!

Comment: you dont need to first join the domain. it's unnecessary due the fact that you create a new domain controller which is literally already a member of the domain. But i would suggest that you do not use the same server for a FS. in both cases I suggest you to use a second drive for the data. But in fact yes that is the basic way. remind to set first the name of the server before installing the DC Role

Comment: Not for nothing, but you can perform a two-hop in-place upgrade from 2012 to 2012 R2 or 2016 to 2019 and save yourself a lot of time and effort.

Comment: I don't think you need a migration tool to copy data. Unless robocopy is a migration tool.  You typically may need to create a CNAME for the old server name.